# Application Design: How to Model a Composite Web Application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I have a web application (let's take for Project B) that is supposed to provide some features over a certain class set (called here Project A), using and improving it. I'm developing over Spring MVC and Hibernate.

Supose the following very simple example:

```
Project A
+Medic
  +id:long
  +name:String
  +area:Area

+Area
  +id:long
  +name:String

+Nurser
  +id:long
  +name:String

Project B
+Surgery
  +id:long
  +doctor:Medic
  +nurser:Nurser

+DoctorOnCall
  +id:long
  +doctor:Medic
  +dateTime:Calendar
```

I'm supposed to implement CRUD for classes from both project A and B; Project A would be used futurely in order to provide classes and methods for Projects C, D, etc, in ways that project B is a kind of "child" of project A.

Given that characteristics, what would be the best implementation strategy? Do I have to build a web application for project A and, in this case, how to use it in project B? Should I have two webapps running in same server (Projects A and B)? If yes, how to import project A's classes (including interfaces and DAO) in Project B in order to perform operations of entity retrieving, for example (consider that I shouldn't have a jar from a Webapp)? What's the best practices in order to carry out this task? Thanks!

Comment: You can research SOA and messaging frameworks (e.g. rabbitmq). But, you should consider the big picture and whether the increased complexity (and therefore dev time) in implementing any architecture is even necessary.

Comment: See Maven multi-module projects: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html